# Can I add custom list layout by SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, database, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I am new with android..I am learning work with database files..I have a `simplecurseadapter` like this

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null, null, null, null, COLUMN_ID);

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, 
                   new String[] {COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_order}, new int[] {R.id.list_item_text_id,R.id.list_item_text_main,R.id.list_item_text_sub}, 0);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to know Is there any way to make a custom listview?my column_order has just to value 0,1 and I want rows with 0 value shows in `R.id.list_item_text_main` and if its value is 1 it shows in `R.id.list_item_text_sub` Can I define an if statement in `SimpleCursorAdapter`?I yes How?If no..Whats the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your query like this

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,COLUMN_order + "=? OR " + COLUMN_order + "=?", new String[]{"0", "1"}, null, null, COLUMN_ID);



SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, 
               new String[] {COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_order}, new int[] {R.id.list_item_text_id,R.id.list_item_text_main,R.id.list_item_text_sub}, 0);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: But this code will show all names in R.id.list_item_text_main and all orders in R.id.list_item_text_sub I just want to show orders with value 1 in R.id.list_item_text_sub and with 0 in R.id.list_item_text_sub..I think I must use an if statement to do this..But I do not know how to do this

Comment: Then you query your database to return only those values

Comment: But I Already ding this with my code..right?I think I must use some clasess like this

Comment: `private class CustomViewBinder implements ViewBinder {
 
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(ClubCP.KEY_IS_STAR)) {
            // If the column is IS_STAR then we use custom view.
            int is_star = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            if (is_star != 1) {
                // set the visibility of the view to GONE
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return true;
        }
   
        return false;
    }
 
} `

Comment: Your cursor c should only contains rows that only has values 0 or 1 in COLUMN_order.

Comment: You make your life very hard doing thing that way. Just query right then all you need is the code that is posted in your question. Your query should include the WHERE COLUMN_order = 0 OR COLUMN_order = 1

Comment: You mean I can do this at same time in one listview?If I change to where column_order=0 it just show column orders with 0 but I want to show both of them in list..if column_order=1 show column name in R.id.list_item_text_main and if it is 0 show it in R.id.list_item_text_sub in one query I have both of them

Comment: Why check so fast, If you mean column_order = 1, then whatever is in column_name for this row should go to R.id.list_item_text_main and if column_order = 0 then the name should go to R.id.list_item_text_sub. Then you cannot do it using SimpleCursorAdapter. Use ArrayAdapter and override ViewBinder

Answer (score 1):

I think I find my answer...
http://enjoyandroid.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/customizing-simple-cursor-adapter/
I am working on it..Maybe I am wrong